# Error in installing request module in Python

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am facing some errors while installing requests module in python 3.10 version.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjDew.png)I am attaching screenshot of the errors.

Comment: Need more of the stack trace (preferably, all of it). Use a pastebin or something similar and link it to the question, instead of the screenshot.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

You can try any one of these commands:

"pip install requests"

"python -m pip install requests"

Or go to this official python packages page to check how you can install the requests library.
https://pypi.org/project/requests/

Comment: I already tried that but it still doesn’t work.

Comment: @ohdarling try this command: "pip install git+https://github.com/psf/requests.git"

Answer (score 0):

Please use one of the following commands :

```
pip install requests
```

Or

```
pip3 install requests
```